# Imagick: Including PNG leads to displaying strange symbols

Tags: php, image, imagick

I'm using the following code to display an image which is stored on my webspace:

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');          

$filePath                       =   JPATH_SITE.'/images/powered_by.png';
$image                          =   new Imagick("{$filePath}[0]"); // [0] means "first page"
$image->setImageFormat('png');
echo $image;            
exit;
```

This happens in a modal-view of my Joomla-Component. The result is the following:

[image: Modal with symbols]

What can I do to display the image I wanted to display?

Comment: Where exactly is this code? PHP scripts that output images generally need to be isolated - they can't run as part of a framework, which may output other stuff that interferes.

Comment: Hi Jonathon, the code is located in a controller which is embedded into my Joomla! component.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think that will work. You're probably also getting a *Warning: headers already sent* warning as well.

Comment: No, I do not get this warning - it's not shown and I don't get them in my logs aswell.

Hm, so I have to take a look if Joomla! provides something to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a combination of things going wrong.

i. you have errors disabled, which is not showing the real problem.

ii. you have some whitespace at the beginning or end of a file. This is causing the headers to be sent before the code reaches the `header('Content-Type: image/png');`.

iii. Because the headers have already been sent (with the default text content type) the browser is interpreting the image data as text, and so rendering it as text.

There's nothing wrong with the code you have posted. What you need to do is find out what is causing the png content type not being sent to the browser - which I strongly suspect is going to be done by turning on the display of errors.

Comment: Hm, I created a test.php with only this content - no Joomla! Framework around it. That works.

Thanks for your help, now I have to check how to implement this into Joomla!